# Is there any cost effective static stress simulation for rapid prototyping (FDM / 3D-printing)?

Tags: simulation, 3d-printing

I've been using the static stress simulation (computed locally) which, until recently, has been free with the Personal licence of Fusion 360. Is there a reasonable alternative?

The cost that Autodesk charges for cloud credits works out to be much greater than is generally the cost to print a part and perform a real world test. I'd rather not landfill the PETG/PLA; but I'm willing to if that's what it takes to avoid the hundred's of dollars cost to simulate. The cost to add locally computed simulation back to Fusion 360 is prohibitive even if it was a one-time-cost; but, worse, it's a subscription.

Is there any free for personal use static stress simulation software? Is there some way to restore locally computed simulation to fusion 360? Is there some other viable solution?

Comment: I'm totally open to any suggestions which would make this question better.

Comment: lots of discussion online about this already e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/fea/comments/4mtqak/who_uses_an_open_source_fea_workflow/ That said, I would recommend real world testing if you have the facilities, as FEA doesn't work well with the complexities of FDM prints, namely non-isotropic strength due to layer orientation, and complex stiffness due to infill patterns. If you are creating so much waste as to be a problem, set up a regrind/re-extrusion system.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or right, the non-isotropic strength has been negligible in all my real world tests. I set the simulation data based on my worst case real world test of the materia,l to be safe.

Comment: I have done a few hours of searching. Perhaps I don't know the correct words or acronyms to investigate. I avoid reddit though, reading or posting; so if that's the standard place then I'd have missed it. I find the reddit experience like wading through garbage in the hope that I find a laptop with bitcoin on it. Still, I appreciate the link, and have started reading through the discourse.